# Non-normal residual distribution using mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, linear, assumptions

I am pretty much a beginner in statistics/R and I would need your advice.

I have tried to look for the answer for my problem (believe me, I prefer to search rather than post) but it only increased my uncertainty regarding the appropriate course of action.

I am trying to fit a linear mixed model on my data, however, during diagnostics I found out that the residual distribution is not normal. It seems there are heavy tails on both sides and I suspect it might be because of non-normal distribution of my DV. I treat the DV as a continuous variable, although it has, in fact, "only" 39 levels.

The design is a repeated measures where every participant comes to the lab twice  receiving a three different stimualtions (treatments). The other day receive the same kind of treatments as the previous session but just in the other hemisphere.
I want to find the effect of the condition (treatment) on risk.

My model is: y = risk ~ condition + (1|day) + (1|session) + (1|trial_type) + (1|participant), using ML.

I am attaching screenshots of the model_check() and distribution of the DV risk.

Could somebody give me advice how should I proceed? Should I be concerned?

[image: Distribution of the DV risk]
[image: Model diagnostics]¨

Comment: If you give us more information about your data, the model you have fitted, and your general goal, we might be able to give more insight. In general, if you want to fit mixed models with nonnormal residuals, you should have a look e.g. at the [glmm](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) package.

Comment: What does your univariate data look like without applying the regression model to it? As someone above said, your data may require a GLMM rather than LMER, or some form of transformation of the data.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have clarified some things in my previous post because I believe it has been incomplete. Could you help me?

Comment: *I mean I've edited the original entry and added the description as well as equation of the model and some other information.